# Wrap Activity in a fragment, or an alternative solution

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a kinda big, already published railway schedule app published on Google Play, and now I am planning to integrate bus schedules as well. My question is something like this:

- At the moment, whenever the app starts, it loads the Activity, where you can search for train, lets call it A
- I have already implemented a beta version of the bus search Activity, lets call it B
- Eventually, I will come up with a hybrid solution, that will be able to search for trains AND buses at the same time, of course with some restrictions, lets call it C

Now, I want to implement the main screen so it will have swipeable tabs, and the tabs would be A, B, and C. I never really worked with theese kind of tabs, so my knowledge is not that deep, however, I came up with a solution, that would indeed work, but it is going to need a lot of recoding(keep in mind, my app was published more then a year ago), since I never really prepared for fragments. I am doing pretty much [THIS](http://android.amolgupta.in/2013/01/backward-compatibility-super-quick.html) thingie, and it works really great. However, this means that the main screen should be a FragmentActivity, which is fine, I can deal with that. But I just cannot supply A, B, and C Activity, as tabs, it will accept only fragments.

The question is: can I supplement my already coded Activity as a fragment, so I can swipe between them? Is there any wrapping mechanic I am not aware of? Any other solution, which you can show me? Just point me in the direction, I will do the rest. Or, am I f**ked, and have to recode everything from scratch? No problem, if that's the case, tho I would happily avoid it.

Thanks in advance, cheers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both for the suggestions, I did try the method wangyif2 suggested, it generates way too much overhead in the code, since I did some kinda specific things.

I am going to check out some demos, but I guess I will recode everything from scratch, that seems to be the most clean solution at this point.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to wrap your fragment in an Activity. This would be the better choice if you've got multiple classes enclosed in your Activity. Otherwise, I would just go with [wangyif2's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175032/2109241) instead.

In any case, should you want to do the former:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
  ...

  public static class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
    ...

  }
}
```

And when you finally initialize all this in an ActionBar

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
            .setText("Sample")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<SampleActivity.SampleFragment>(
                    this, "sample", SampleActivity.SampleFragment)));
```

I suggest checking out the API Demo from API 14+ samples. There's a really good example of this in FragmentTabs (com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentTabs).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your original Activity A, B, C extending SherlockActivity, simply change them to extend SherlockFragments, and supply them to the Tabs.

Obviously there will be some compilation errors that you have to fix, namely the difference between activity lifecycle and [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle), but once you fix them, you should be good to go.